# ERRO syntax error, unexpected T_VARIABLE

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theme, sintaxe

Estou com um problema e sou iniciante em PHP, não sei se é fácil de corrigir este erro.

> (Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_VARIABLE in
>   /home/u611580299/public_html/wp-content/themes/simplicityantigo/includes/google-fonts.php
>   on line 1)

```
<?php
global $fontArrays;

$fontArrays = array(
    0 =>
    array(
        'kind' => 'webfonts#webfont',
        'family' => 'ABeeZee',
        'variants' =>
        array(
            0 => 'regular',
            1 => 'italic',
        ),
        'subsets' =>
        array(
            0 => 'latin',
        ),
    ),
    // ...
);
?>
```

[Arquivo completo](http://runnable.com/VJIkBDqh0zcMGYSB/wordpress-for-php)

Comment: Não se declara variáveis globais fora do escopo das funções, simples.

Comment: Além disso, sinceramente, com um tanto de array dentro de array como tens aí, a chance de ter esquecido um ponto-vírgula..... é enorme. rsrs

Comment: @ZebraDoMal ponto e virgula dentro de array? Viajou hein

Comment: Para quem votou para fechar: Como não é reproduzível ?

Comment: É uma ótima pergunta, muita gente vai ter esse mesmo problema.

Comment: Pelo tamanho desse Array não aconselho, mas se quiser utilizar uma GLOBAL fora do escopo de uma função você deve usar a superglobal `$GLOBALS[]`.

Comment: @DanielRibeiro mas da forma que está a variável já está no escopo global

Comment: @gmsantos Sim, realmente, se ele apenas desprezar a primeira declaração, que deve ser usada dentro de funções, a variável esta global no arquivo, mas se ele quiser tornar-lá global pra todo o projeto, ele pode usar o que citei em cima, embora não seja aconselhável por questão de performance, pois o array eh gigante. Se eu estiver falando basteira, por favor, me corrija.

Comment: Mas na verdade acho que o problema dele mesmo era apenas erro de sintaxe, eu que interpretei errado achando que ele queria carregar a variavel para fora do arquivo. Erro meu.

Comment: Não exatamente @DanielRibeiro. Supondo que temos o arquivo `i.php` setando algo em `$_GLOBAL`. Caso não tenha em nenhum momento um `include` de `i.php` em um arquivo `m.php`, a variável que defini em `i.php` também não ficará disponível. Acessar usando `global $a` ou `$_GLOBALS['a']` não muda em nada na questão performance.

Comment: Entendi @gmsantos. Valeu por esclarecer. Basicamente, a variável não precisar ser declarada, explicitamente, como $GLOBALS para pertencer ao escopo, apenas o fato de ela existir no arquivo, fora de funções, já a inclui na superglobal. O `globals` serve para explicitar que ele esta utilizando uma variável existente fora do escopo da função. Blz, agora esta tudo entendido xD. Certo?

Comment: Isso ai @DanielRibeiro

Comment: @gmsantos Eu tava falando do ponto-vírgula depois da array. array (); Mas pelo que olhei agora aqui na verdade tem um array só (achei que tinham vários quando olhei rápido). huahua

Answer (score 5, accepted):

O problema aqui está no uso da palavra chave `global`.

`global` serve para referenciar dentro do escopo de uma função uma variável no escopo global:

```
<?php

$a = 5;
$b = 3;

function soma(){
    $a = 1;
    $b = 2;

    return $a + $b;
}

function somaGlobal(){
    // A partir desse ponto, $a = 5 e $b = 3
    global $a, $b;

    return $a + $b;
}

echo soma();        // escreve 3
echo somaGlobal();  // escreve 8
```